# Dynamic report generation

Tags: r

I have a function that takes cell values and generates comments from them.

I'm trying to learn how to use apply effectively.

I pass in a data frame which contains 10 rows and four columns with the aim of making a sentence per row based on the value contained within each cell of the row

```
 report <- iris

 build_comments <- function (report) {

 mydf <- report 
 mycomment <- paste("Analysis Of", mydf[,5],"for flower", mydf[,5], "with     width", mydf[,2], "being the most impacted with ", 
             "Most of the items had length of", mydf[,1],
sep = " ")
  cat(mycomment)
}


apply(report[,c(2,3,10,11)],1,build_comments)
```

Unfortunately, it is building a single comment with every item in the column added to the place holders. Can anyone see the mistake

I would also take the `purrr` approach if you think it is easier.

Comment: `paste` is vectorized. No need for an `apply` loop. `cat` is not appropriate for anything other than its intended use, in particular not as a return value for a function since it returns an invisible `NULL`. `sprintf` seems more convenient for this use case.

Comment: If you need more help, present a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Try this example: `mtcars$comment <-
  with(mtcars,
       paste("This car has", cyl, "cylinders",
             "and", gear, "gears."))`

Comment: Hi @Roland thanks for your quick reply, cat was just in there to see what was happening. I will update the code to include a reproducible example

Comment: Hi @zx8754 this is what i am looking for. Can you give me a bit of more information on the with section of your piece of code? Please submit it as an answer and i will mark it

Comment: This is more readable: `with(mtcars, sprintf("This car has %i cylinders and %i gears.", cyl, gear))`. `with` simply evaluates the expression within the data.frame and saves you from typing `mtcars$` repeatedly.

Comment: Can I strongly, strongly recommend you look into `knitr`

Comment: Hi @Phil, I use Knitr/Bookdown and Markdown a lot. Unfortunately this text needs to go into the body of an email so we write it to an excel workbook with MS Charts and that gets posted into the email body and the excel workbook gets attached for management.

Comment: @JohnSmith I should have known: if there's a convoluted, contrived method going on, it's usually because management have asked for it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
mtcars$comment <-
  with(mtcars,
       paste("This car has", cyl, "cylinders",
             "and", gear, "gears."))
```

Or as Roland suggested, using `sprintf()`:

```
mtcars$comment <- 
  with(mtcars,
       sprintf("This car has %i cylinders and %i gears.",
               cyl, gear))
```

`with()` simply evaluates the expression within the data.frame and saves you from typing `mtcars$` repeatedly.

```
# without using "with()"
mtcars$comment <- 
  sprintf("This car has %i cylinders and %i gears.",
          mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear)
```